# How to render array of arrays of objects with mustache

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, backbone.js, mustache

I am trying to render an array of arrays of objects with a mustache template in javascript, and I have not found anyone else who has asked this question. I can render an array of objects just fine, but I can't figure out how to render an array of them. I could assign each nested array to its own variable I suppose, but there could be any number of them, so I really need to keep them as an array.

Here is the type of data I need to render:

```
[
    [
        { id: 12345, name: "Billy" },
        { id: 23456, name: "Joe" },
        { id: 34567, name: "Jenny" }
    ],
    [
        { id: 45678, name: "Amy" },
        { id: 56789, name: "Julie" },
        { id: 67890, name: "Sam" }
    ]
]
```

The outer array could contain any number of nested arrays, and each nested array could contain any number objects.

I don't know if it's possible with mustache. I tried using a function, and this is the first time I've ever used a function with mustache, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. I am calling it from the render function of a Backbone View. The array of arrays (shown above) is part of the view's model's attributes. So here is what I tried.

```
render:
    function ()
    {
        this.model.attributes.getList =
            function ()
            {
                return  function (str, func) { return 'What in the world should I return here?'; }
            }

        this.$el.html (Mustache.render ($ ('#detail-template').html (), this.model.attributes));

        return this;
    },
```

And here is the section of my template where I am attempting to use the function.

```
{{#getList}}
    {{name}}
{{/getList}}
```

I am pretty sure {{name}} doesn't belong in there, but I have no idea what else I would put in there.

I tried returning func (str), but all it printed was a long string that contained [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

I could not use that string as a json object, it was just a string.

I'm somewhat new to both backbone and mustache, so I thought someone might have a "best practice" solution to this, or at least could tell me if it is impossible so I don't waste any more time on it. I could not find a similar question anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: couldnt you just flatten your array? with underscore´s flatten function? Btw. in there render you should not give back "model.attributes" but "model.toJSON()".

Comment: @Luke is right, if you're using Mustache then you're going to be doing pretty much all your data wrangling in JavaScript before you get anywhere near the template.

Answer (score 7):

This question is 2 years old but I guess better late than never. You can use {{.}} to reference the current element in an array.

```
context = [
    [
        { id: 12345, name: "Billy" },
        { id: 23456, name: "Joe" },
        { id: 34567, name: "Jenny" }
    ],
    [
        { id: 45678, name: "Amy" },
        { id: 56789, name: "Julie" },
        { id: 67890, name: "Sam" }
    ]
]

template = "
    {{#context}}
        {{#.}}
            <span id={{id}}>{{name}}</span>
        {{/.}}
    {{/context}}
"
```

Comment: It should actually be {{/.}}. Otherwise, this will work.

Comment: Thank @Cary, fixed it.