# Iterate through an array of arrays with Mustache

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I have checked all similar questions, no one seem to have answered this.

```
$data = ['data' => array(
    ['id'=>'1','name'=>'Dupe', 'country' => 'Nigeria'], 
    ['id'=>'3','name'=>'Dipo', 'country' => 'Togo']
)];

$mustache->render('index', $data);
```

index.html looks like this:

```
<div>Hello</div>

<br>

<h2>Search for a person</h2>
<form action="/search" method="POST">
    Input user's name or email:
    <br><input type="text" name="key" value="" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

{{ #data }}
    <div> {{ name }} - {{ country }} </div>
{{ /data }}
```

It is currently returning a blank page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395357/how-to-render-array-of-arrays-of-objects-with-mustache/34587017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure that out, but converting the inner array to objects works just fine:

```
$m = new Mustache_Engine();
$data = [
    'data' => array(
        ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'Dupe', 'country' => 'Nigeria'],
        ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'Dipo', 'country' => 'Togo']
    )
];
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data));

echo $m->render(
    '{{#data}}
       <div> {{ name }} - {{ country }} </div>
    {{/data}}',
    $data
);
```

This outputs:

> `<div> Dupe - Nigeria </div>`
>      `<div> Dipo - Togo </div>`

Notice `{{#data}}` and `{{/data}}` have no spaces!

I've used an inline template string as i didn't have yours.